# Como activar conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

```
C:\Users\cjfor>python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: No veo la relación entre el título, que parece una pregunta, y el cuerpo de la pregunta, que no lo es.

Answer (score 1):

La razón por la que aparece este "*Warning*" es que en tus variables de entorno están agregadas las direcciones de los binarios de ANACONDA:
En windows puedes ver tus variables ejecutando la aplicación "**Editar las variables de entorno del sistema**", al revisar la variable `Path` te encontrarás algo como esto:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3                                                                                              C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin                                                                        C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin                                                                              C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin                                                                                  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts

El hecho de que estén estas rutas aquí, te posibilita ejecutar el comando `python` desde el CMD, pero la forma correcta de iniciar python desde la terminal con ANACONDA es activando primero el *enviroment*:

```sh
conda activate
```

De otra forma tendrás un mensaje en consola, advirtiéndote que el interprete de python que estas usando se encuentra en un *enviroment* de conda pero que ¡No has activado! lo cual es cierto.
Tienes 3 opciones para que no aparezca este *Warning* (de menos recomendable a mas recomendable):

- Borrar las rutas hacia Anconda3 en la variable de entorno `Path` (lo menos recomendable)
- Acostumbrarte a escribir `conda activate` en el CMD antes de `python`
- Abrir siempre una terminal de conda con la aplicación **Anaconda Prompt** (lo mas recomendable)

Answer (score 0):

No tienes ningún error, sólo acabas de inicializar python. Si deseas activar un ambiente primero debes crearlo.

Una opción más fácil. Descargar anaconda navigator. Al tenerlo instalado inicias la app -> sección enviroments. Esquina Inferior 'Create' le pones el nombre de tu agrado y esperas mientras se crea. Al finalizar, Te aparecerá en la lista de ambientes presionas clic -> open in terminal. Se inicia por defecto.

O directamente de la consola es tan sencillo como:

Para crear:

```
~$ conda create -n nombredeentorno python=x.x anaconda
```

Para activar

```
~$ source activate -- nombreambientecreado
```

Para desactivar

```
~$ source deactivate
```